# Is there a node.js api that allows to store the current running node process and resume it later?

Tags: node.js, process, operating-system, v8

Googling for it results in many “how to persist data in a node app” but I’m looking on a way to store the program counter, memory status, event loop, call stack etc in persistent storage, and resume it later.

Benefits: if you see the runtime (a server, container, serverless function) is about to  terminate, instead of using business logic to pause and resume (custom work), use the same way operating systems handle multiple processes / threads. Store everything, then resume it later form a different infrastructure (but with identical specs).

I’m sure there is something like this, but simply can’t find the right search term probably.

Ps this might be an OS feature that I’m looking for and not node specific, but if this can be done from within Node’s API (Eg v8 internals) I can basically get an unlimited / long running lambda ;) (which is a bad idea but I want to know if it’s possible).

Answer (score 1):

(V8 developer here.)

V8 definitely doesn't support this.

What V8 does support is taking a heap snapshot, and deserializing that on renewed process startup (and I believe Node is making use of this functionality). That's quite different from freezing an entire running process though.

I'm not sure what you mean by "the same way operating systems handle multiple processes / threads". Operating systems don't usually let you snapshot a process and transfer it to a different machine.

On the same machine, you could literally just let the OS do it: pause the process (e.g. press Ctrl+Z if you started it at a Linux command line, or use equivalent Task Manager functionality if your OS provides it, or similar), and resume it later. If the process itself doesn't fire any repeated tasks/timers, then that's almost equivalent to simply doing nothing: a process that executes no work won't get scheduled by the kernel anyway; a server that isn't serving any requests can just sit around waiting.

If you actually need to transfer a running process to another machine, your best bet may be a VM which you can snapshot, transfer, resume.